# Graphs and First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, relations, predicate-logic, model-theory

I have tried to solve a problem and I would like to check if I have done it correctly:

> Let $\mathcal{V}=(V,E)$ be a graph, i.e. $E$ is a binary relation on $V$ that is symmetric and irreflexive. We consider $\mathcal{V}$ as a structure in the vocabulary $L=\{ R\}$ where $R$ is a binary predicate and $R^\mathcal{V}=E$. Find statements that express in $\mathcal{V}$ the following: (a) The graph has a clique (a complete subgraph) of $5$ or more vertice. (b) The graph is not complete, i.e. not every pair of vertices is connected by an edge.

(a) A graph has a clique of $5$ or more vertices if and only if there exist $5$ vertices, let us denote them by $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$ and $v$, such that $x\neq y$, $x\neq z$, $x\neq u$, $x\neq v$, $y\neq z$, $y\neq u$, $y\neq v$, $z\neq u$, $z\neq v$, $u\neq v$ and the pairs of vertices $(x,y)$, $(x,z)$, $(x,u)$, $(x,v)$, $(y,z)$, $(y,u)$, $(y,v)$, $(z,u)$, $(z,v)$, $(u,v)$ are connected by edges.

Hence, we obtain the formula

$$\exists x\exists y\exists z\exists u\exists v(\neg x=y\wedge \neg x=z\wedge \neg x=u\wedge \neg x=v\wedge \neg y=z\wedge \neg y=u\wedge \neg y=v\wedge \neg z=u\wedge \neg z=v\wedge \neg u=v\wedge Rxy\wedge Rxz\wedge Rxu\wedge Rxv\wedge Ryz\wedge Ryu\wedge Ryv\wedge Rzu\wedge Rzv\wedge Ruv)$$

(b) A graph is not complete if and only if there exist two different vertices not connected by an edge.

Hence, we obtain the formula

$$\exists x\exists y(\neg x=y\wedge \neg Rxy)$$

Comment: yes, this is correct :) ... for future advice, your first formula could be notationally simplified slightly by using variables $x_1,\dots,x_5$ and the "\bigwedge" notation of LaTeX, as follows: $$\exists x_1\dots\exists x_5\left[\bigwedge_{i\neq j}\neg(x_i=x_j)\wedge\bigwedge_{i\neq j} R(x_i,x_j)\right]$$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Beat me by a few seconds! (If you turn your comment into an answer I'll delete mine since you were first.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber no worries!! :) I feel like it's useful to demonstrate two slightly different notational preferences anyway, so that OP can choose which style they might want to use going forward!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks right. Re: (a), note that "indexed connectives" can simplify things: what you've written is equivalent to $$\exists x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5[(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le 5}\neg x_i=x_j)\wedge(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le 5}R(x_i,x_j))].$$

This indexed connective notation isn't actually part of the formalism of first-order logic, but it's a commonly-used abbreviation system which $(i)$ is automatic to unpack (so it's clear that the writer *could* have written out a genuine FOL expression) and $(ii)$ often much more readable.

Comment: Since the OP is probably a beginner, it would be good to point out explicitly that the indexed connectives are (usually) not part of the _formalism_, but are just a compact way to _write down_ the exact same formula he has already constructed.

Comment: @Troposphere Fair point, 'tis done!

Comment: I am hesitating with the hypothesis that $R$ is irreflexive, so this would take me away from many cases of non-equalities. Could I remove non-equalities with the condition that $R$ is irreflexive?

Comment: @zkdohbklnbpowtmlkp I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but note that in the indexed expressions I never allowed a variable to be compared with itself (note "$i<j$" rather than "$i\le j$" both times). So I don't see how there's a reflexivity issue here.

Comment: If $R$ is irreflexive and $Rxy$, then it would not be necessary to put that $\neg x=y$, can it be?

Comment: @zkdohbklnbpowtmlkp's question was whether he can get away with omitting the $\neq$ conjuncts, given that he has been promised that the relation is irreflexive. I'd say yes, they can be omitted -- for example, $x_2\ne x_4$ is then already implied by $R(x_2,x_4)$.

Comment: @zkdohbklnbpowtmlkp I was just illustrating how the indexed connective notation would transform the specific example you gave. Since you included $\not=$ clauses, so did I. And anyways if we assume irreflexivity it's fine to include them, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: @Troposphere Yeah, just figured that out. :P

Comment: In (b), could I also omit $\neg x=y$?

Comment: @zkdohbklnbpowtmlkp No, because "$\neg R$" **does** allow for two vertices to be equal. (You could get rid of it if you assumed that $R$ **was** reflexive, though.)